# ios - deserialized json data as a two-level dictionary. how to make it an array with dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am deserializing data into a dictionary, but the result is a nested dictionary so it looks like:

```
{"0":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
{"1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
{"2":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
```

I want to use this in a tableview so how would I go about turning that dictionary into an Array where each objet in the array is a dictionary with the value pairs?

I want to be able to step through the array, and reference the value pairs for each row of the array.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Given this, and from your unclear description  it's hard to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: Once you've managed to decode the JSON into arrays/dictionaries, forget that it's JSON.  Study the array/dictionary structure and peel it apart one layer at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in outerDictionary.allValues) {
  [tableArray addObject:dict];
}
```

Indeed, or simpler:

```
tableArray = outerDictionary.allValues;
```

Comment: Isn't this just long hand for `tableArray = [outerDictionary.allValues copy`]  ?  You could even omit the copy ;)   (erm, also didn't you mean **addObject**?

Comment: Ah, now I understand the question.  ;)